# Is it possible to use PHPMailer with local domain?

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHP is a new thing for me and I'm trying to build this simple form to send mail. I've seen tutorials and documentations and it seems that I need mail hosting (got one) and a domain for this hosting. So my question is is it possible to build this form using just XAMPP or do I have to have real domain?

Comment: You can install a local mailserver, if that's what you mean. Or you can just use it with something like Gmail, for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your PHPMailer web app on XAMPP on localhost. Later you can transfer the web form to your website hosting on your domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku you can run locally using the [Heroku CLI tools](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-local-processname).